# Creating and calling a custom function inside an angular class

Tags: angular, express, parsing, parameters, components

I created a custom function inside a class, how do I call it within the same class?

A user enters a word in an input field. It triggers the "onNameKeyUp" function below. I have to verify if the word is plural: if yes I turn it into a singular form. 
I am giving below a very simplified example:

```
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  spelling="";

  tokenizeSpellingEnglish(item: string): string{
  if (item =="houses"){
    item = "house";
  }
     return item;
  }

   onNameKeyUp(event: any){
    this.spelling = event;
    this.spelling = this.spelling.toLowerCase();
    this.tokenizeSpellingEnglish(this.spelling);
    this.elem.nativeElement.focus();   
   }
```

The singular form will then be sent to the server for further processing.

the application works fine without the spelling verification.

As a side note, I am wondering if this is the right approach at all: should I parse the user input on the server instead? That being said, still I would love to know what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: calling the method defined in the same class? your question

Comment: @Hearn yes that's exactly what I don't know how to do

Comment: answer updated long time ago, man. please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and your example code is truly representative of your real code, I see that you are calling `tokenizeSpellingEnglish` but never storing the returned value back into `this.spelling`:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  spelling="";

  tokenizeSpellingEnglish(item: string): string{
  if (item =="houses"){
    item = "house";
  }
     return item;
  }

   onNameKeyUp(event: any){
    this.spelling = event;
    this.spelling = this.spelling.toLowerCase();

    // --> this.tokenizeSpellingEnglish(this.spelling); should be
    this.spelling = this.tokenizeSpellingEnglish(this.spelling);

    this.elem.nativeElement.focus();   
   }
```

You could also have `tokenizeSpellingEnglish` work directly on this.spelling, if that suits your use case.

If your code is instead simply failing to execute properly, I'd look at how you are unpacking the event parameter in `onNameKeyUp`.  If you are handling the raw event object from the 'keyup' event, you need to get the value from the `target` property on the event object and work with that:

```
onNameKeyUp(event: any) {
  this.spelling = event.target.value;
  // the rest of your function as before
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot! that did it

Answer (score 0):

Validating the input in frontend is okay, calling the method defined in the same class, we use `this` as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h3>Check the console below</h3>
     <input #myInput (keydown)="showValue(myInput.value)"/>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  showValue(value: string) {
      this.printTheValue(value);
  }

  printTheValue(value: string) {
      console.log("the current input value: " + value);
  }
}
```

An online [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-absfyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to better help you check the result.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply but it doesn't really answer the question, or I don't understand the answer.

Comment: Your question is not as you mentioned **I created a custom function inside a component, how do I call it within the same component?**??

Comment: Sorry maybe I should re-phrase it: created inside the class part of the component and calling it within it as well

Comment: Please update your question with proper intention: what do you wanna achieve **exactly**? what's the problem now?